# Pointwise convergence vector valued continuous functions

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, pointwise-convergence

Let $(X,\|\cdot\|)$ be a (infinite dimensional) Banach space and $f_{n}:[0,1]\longrightarrow (X,\|\cdot\|)$ continuous, for each integer $n\geq 1$, a sequence of mappings. There is some "pointwise compactness criteria" for this sequence? That is, a criteria which state (of course, under suitable conditions) the convergence of some subsequence of the sequence $f_{n}(t)$, for a given $t\in [0,1]$.

Many thanks in advance for your comments.

Comment: In particular if each $f_n$ is constant then you are asking: is there a criterium for which a sequence has a convergent subsequence. I don't think there is in an infinite dimensional case, right?

Comment: Well, we "omit" the case that $f_{n}$ be constant. Maybe, the right question colud be "a criteria for compactness of sequencess in (infinite dimensional) Banach spaces", no?

Comment: A compactness criterion follows immediately from Tychonov's theorem: A set $\mathcal F$ of functions $[0,1]\to X$ is (relatively) compact with respect to the topology of pointwise convergence if and only if all set $\mathcal F(t)=\{f(t): f\in\mathcal F\}$ are (relatively) compact in $X$. HOWEVER, this does not imply sequential compactness!